# Java - How to convert data from mysql database to a JSON Array?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I have a mysql database with the table "trips" with some columns, it looks like this:

[image: Table Example]

Each row contains the data for one trip. And I want to search for the "asg_id" and want to get all rows(trips) with this "asg_id" .

My question is, how to convert this data with the individual trips tho a JSON Array?
Or, how can I get all trips with this "asg_id"?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json .put("json", collection/object);

request.setAttribute("jsonObject", json.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Cursor c= dbo.rawQuery("SELECT * from trips where asg_id="
                    + id, null);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObjectInner = new JSONObject();   

 if (c!= null && c.getCount() > 0) {

 c.moveToFirst();

try {
do{

jsonObjectInner.put("trip_id", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("trip_id"));
jsonObjectInner.put("asg_id", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("asg_id"));
jsonObjectInner.put("date_start", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_start"));
jsonObjectInner.put("time_start",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_start"));
jsonObjectInner.put("time_stop", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time_stop"));
jsonObject.put("trip", jsonObjectInner);
 }while(c.moveToNext());

}
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```