# How to cast multiple columns from sql query into one object in java?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, json, casting

Alright guys, 
I'm just trying to get a list of objects from my table 'ItemList'. I feel like I'm just messing up the query that I'm using. This is the code I'm running:

```
    public List<GetListsDTO> getAllLists() {
        Query query = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT L.name, L.listType, L.position FROM ItemList L ORDER BY L.position ASC");

        try{
            System.out.println(query.list());
            return (List<GetListsDTO>) query.list();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And this is the result on Postman:

```
[
    [
        "list1",
        "Clothing",
        1
    ],
    [
        "list2",
        "Clothing",
        2
    ]
]
```

As you can see it retrieves the right information, but I can't figure out how to cast this into an actual object instead of having it as arrays of strings.

Help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:
This is the result I'm looking for:

```
[
    {
        "name": "list1",
        "listType": "Clothing",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "list2",
        "listType": "Clothing",
        "position": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: they are all objects, you should be more specific, also mysql and other rdms can output json as well, that is a possiblity

Comment: I'm not sure if you get notified by my edit, I made the preferred situation more specific. Maybe you could help me out. @nbk

Comment: as i said directly in mysql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379551/gouping-and-suming-multiple-columns/60380525#60380525 or in java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576645/java-how-to-convert-data-from-mysql-database-to-a-json-array there various possibilitys search please there many solutions for it